# How to send data from one window to another

Tags: pyqt5

I think There is answer for my qestion but it is for pyqt4 and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I made 2 windows on qt desiger. Bothe of them are Ui type files. 
The "nadrzedny" is main window and "dodaj" is second window. 
"nadrzedny" has QlistWidget which supposed to listed item added by "dodaj" window QLineEdit. 
1. How make send data from "dodaj" window to "nadrzedny" window. 
2. Is it possible to make one click to QpushButton - assign function 
   for example pass data to "nadrzedny" window and save date on the file at 
   the same time.

The "nadrzedny" in py file type

'''

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '/home/konrad   /Przyklad/nadrzedny.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 110, 301, 331))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 291, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 470, 301, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lista nieruchomości"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dodaj"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

'''

The "dodaj" file in python type:

'''
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '/home/konrad/Przyklad/dodaj.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 131, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.wpr_dane = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.wpr_dane.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 30, 211, 27))
        self.wpr_dane.setObjectName("wpr_dane")
        self.zatwierdz2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.zatwierdz2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 240, 171, 27))
        self.zatwierdz2.setObjectName("zatwierdz2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "adres nieruchomości"))
        self.zatwierdz2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Zatwierdz"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

'''

My program is:

```
import os
PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic


os.chdir('/home/konrad/Przyklad')                        #Scieżka domyślna do mojego pliku

class Window2(QDialog):                                  # Okno w którym     będę wpisywał dane nieruchomości
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('dodaj.ui', self)




class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):                         # Okno główne programu
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('nadrzedny.ui', self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.okno2)       # zdefiniowany przycisk otwierajacy Window 2
        self.show()

    def okno2(self):
        self.w = Window2()
        self.w.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just made it open but I don know how to send entered text from one window to another.

Comment: Which data do you want to transmit between windows?

Comment: data entered in QlineEdit in window2 "dodaj"  to QListWidget in Ui "nadrzedny".

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

main.py

```
import sys
import os
import datetime                             # +
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog

#from PyQt5 import uic                      # -
from nadrzedny import Ui_MainWindow         # +
from dodaj     import Ui_Dialog             # +

#os.chdir('/home/konrad/Przyklad')              # Scieżka domyślna do mojego pliku

class Window2(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):          # + Ui_Dialog
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        uic.loadUi('dodaj.ui', self)       # -
        self.setupUi(self)                  # +



class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):   # + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

#        uic.loadUi('nadrzedny.ui', self)           # -
        self.setupUi(self)                          # +

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.okno2) # zdefiniowany przycisk otwierajacy Window 2

    def okno2(self):
        self.w = Window2()
        self.w.show()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
        self.w.zatwierdz2.clicked.connect(self.sendText)

    def sendText(self):
        dateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        item = "{} -> {}".format(dateTime, self.w.wpr_dane.text())
        self.listWidget.addItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(item))
        self.w.hide()  
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    window.show()           # +
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

nadrzedny.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 110, 301, 331))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 291, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 470, 301, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lista nieruchomości"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dodaj"))
```

dodaj.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 131, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.wpr_dane = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.wpr_dane.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 30, 211, 27))
        self.wpr_dane.setObjectName("wpr_dane")
        self.zatwierdz2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.zatwierdz2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 240, 171, 27))
        self.zatwierdz2.setObjectName("zatwierdz2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "adres nieruchomości"))
        self.zatwierdz2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Zatwierdz"))
```

[image]

---

**Update**

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
import datetime                             
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog

from PyQt5 import uic                                                   # !

class Window2(QDialog): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('dodaj_nieruchomosc.ui', self)                       # !


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi('nadrzedny.ui', self)                                # !

        self.przycisk.clicked.connect(self.okno2) 

    def okno2(self):
        self.w = Window2()
        self.w.show()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
        self.w.Zatwierdz2.clicked.connect(self.sendText)               # + Zatwierdz2

    def sendText(self):
        dateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        item = "{} -> {}".format(dateTime, self.w.wpr_dane.text())
        self.lista_adr.addItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(item))        # + lista_adr
        self.w.hide()  
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    window.show()           
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**nadrzedny.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QListWidget" name="lista_adr">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>211</width>
      <height>291</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="przycisk">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>27</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Wyświetl Info</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Wybierz Nieruchomość i Kliknij OK</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Dodaj_adr">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>151</width>
      <height>27</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Dodaj Nieruchomość</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Modyfikuj_nier">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>320</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>171</width>
      <height>27</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Modyfikuj Nieruchomość</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>27</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuPliki">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Pliki</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionNowy"/>
    <addaction name="actionWczytaj"/>
    <addaction name="actionZapisz"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="actionUsu"/>
    <addaction name="actionZamknij"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuEdycja">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Edycja</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionEdytuj_Dane"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuPliki"/>
   <addaction name="menuEdycja"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionNowy">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Nowa Nieruchomość</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionWczytaj">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Wczytaj</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionZapisz">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Zapisz</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionUsu">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Usuń</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionZamknij">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Zamknij</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionEdytuj_Dane">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Edytuj Dane</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**dodaj_nieruchomosc.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>604</width>
    <height>366</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="Zatwierdz2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>70</x>
     <y>240</y>
     <width>131</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Zatwierdz</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>40</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Wpisz adres nieruchomości</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="wpr_dane">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>220</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>271</width>
     <height>27</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

Comment: If my example helped you, remember to mark it as the right decision.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post and I do not know anything about mrking . Yes your example help a lot!!! Thank You

Comment: S. Nick your help was very useful - I would like to ask you for one more thing regarding this. I would like to see how to do the same things without cahnging ui file to .py. Just if you could do the same things with 2 ui files and one script in python

Comment: @ConradNiepodam Publish your `dodaj.ui` and `nadrzedny.ui` files in the question.
If my example helped you, remember to mark it as the right decision!

Comment: @ConradNiepodam see Update

Comment: Thank you so much. I am really impressed by your knowledge about pyqt and qt Designer. the code: ```self.lista_adr.addItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(nowy_adres))``` done the trick. I would like to know where I can really learn how to make this kind of coding regarding qt designer and pyqt5. I found manual but there is lot of mess as many of them is for pyqt4 and for C++ language. Is there any place in internet where all of this is for python users?